# Модальное окно (twitter bootstrap) видно при загрузке страницы.

Tags: twitter, bootstrap, javascript

Нужно чтобы модальное окно появлялось при нажатии на кнопку, но при открытии страницы окно висит и не реагирует на закрытие, когда кнопкой вызываешь окно заново, начинает реагировать на отмену и закрытие. Что я делаю не так?

---

HTML (Само окно):

```
<div class="modal" id="registration"></div>
```

(кнопка)

```
<a href="#registration" id="modalToggle" class="button">Регистрация</a>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#registration').modal({
      keyboard: true,
      backdrop: true,
      show: false
    });
    jQuery('#modalToggle').on('click',function(){
        jQuery('#registration').modal('toggle');
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: У вас окно и кнопка представляет собой один и тот же div? Я ничего не понимаю.

Comment: Извините, исправил.

Comment: Попробуйте дописать:

    jQuery('#registration').hide();
    jQuery('#modalToggle').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#registration').modal('toggle');
    });

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.

Comment: на самом деле достаточно добавить класс `hide` к диву модального окна

Comment: Spectre, спасибо, все отлично работает! Очень благодарен вам, извините, что сразу ваш комментарий не заметил и создал еще один вопрос.